# Javascript - use an array for object names then grab properties using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Going crazy trying to do this so I thought I'd get help. I have an array like this:

```
OBJECTS = ["mainmenu","mainviewer","mainsearch"];
```

Each of these is an object like this:

```
mainmenu = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:red};
mainviewer = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:green};
mainsearch = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:blue};
```

Now the crux of it ... I'm simply trying to get the properties like this:

```
for (var item in OBJECTS) {
    var name = OBJECTS[item];
    console.log("the width of "+name+" is "+name.width);
}
```

The console logs back to me:

```
the width of mainmenu is undefined
```

Any help greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Thanks so much ... worked a treat after reordering the declarations ... so objects first then the array of objects and the for loop ... many many thanks ... EJK

Answer (score 1):

Your OBJECTS array is an array of strings.  It's not an array of objects.

Perhaps you meant it to be this:

```
var mainmenu = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"red"};
var mainviewer = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"green"};
var mainsearch = {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"blue"};

var objects = [mainmenu, mainviewer, mainsearch];
```

FYI, I also had to put quotes around the color names because symbols like `red` are not defined.

---

And, if you want to iterate this with a name, you could do this:

```
var mainmenu = {name: "mainmenu", width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"red"};
var mainviewer = {name:"mainview", width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"green"};
var mainsearch = {name: "mainsearch", width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:"blue"};

var objects = [mainmenu, mainviewer, mainsearch];

objects.forEach(function(item) {
    log("the width of "+item.name+" is "+item.width);
});
```

or, a traditional `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var item = objects[i];
    console.log("the width of "+item.name+" is "+item.width);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/abwgjed2/

---

Note: it is a bad idea to iterate arrays with the syntax `for (item in objects)`.  This iterates all properties of the `item` object, not just array elements.  If there are ES5/ES6 polyfills being used, there may be some extra enumerable properties that will show up in the `for (item in objects)` iteration.  Either use `.forEach()` or `for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LLu672ra/)

```
var OBJECTS = 
    {
      mainmenu : {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:'red'},
      mainviewer : {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:'green'},
      mainsearch : {width:250,height:250,backgroundcolor:'blue'}
  }

for (var item in OBJECTS) {
    var name = OBJECTS[item];
    console.log("the width of "+item+" is "+name.width);
}
```